# How can I pass parameters to a alice middleware in Go?

Tags: go, middleware

I am using [justinas/alice](https://github.com/justinas/alice) middleware in Go, and I want to pass arguments to the function used in the middleware.

For example:

```
middlewareChain := alice.New(Func1(foo string,foo2 string))
```

How can I do that?

Comment: you can't, the doc says the middleware func should have the form of `func (http.Handler) http.Handler`, you must to find out a different method like session data or other store mechanism.

Comment: Also want to add that using the Context is another option for this, that's what it's there for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by `Motakjuq`, you can't directly write a middleware that takes in options as an argument since they need to be of the signature `func (http.Handler) http.Handler`.

What you can do is make a function that generates your middleware function.

```
func middlewareGenerator(foo, foo2 string) (mw func(http.Handler) http.Handler) {

    mw = func(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
        return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            // Use foo1 & foo2
            h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        })
    }
    return
}
```

Then you can do the following

`middlewareChain := alice.New(middlewareGenerator("foo","foo2"))`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I didn't understand your question, if your params in `Func1` change in every request, you can't pass the arguments to the function. If your function required some params when you register it with alice, you can return the required function, something like:

```
func Func1(foo, foo2, timeoutMessage string) alice.Constructor {
    //... something to do with foo and foo2
    return func(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
        return http.TimeoutHandler(h, 1*time.Second, timeoutMessage)
    }
}
```

And if you want to use it

```
chain := alice.New(Func1("", "", "time out"))....
```